# Sort a DataTable in .NET with thousands of records using C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable, .net-6.0

I am running a pretty intensive data query (hence the long timeout) but wanted to know how to sort a `DataTable` correctly.

My code starts like so:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
command.CommandTimeout = 36000;

da.SelectCommand = command;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

// Sorting
dv.Sort = "theId DESC";

int i = 0;

while (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && i < 5)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    string theId = row["theId"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

The `theId` has about 2,000 records with that are numerically sequential from 1 to 2,000.

The caveats or not using an `ORDER BY` in the SQL are due to the exception:

> ERROR: Exception occurred
> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a worktable is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of 8060 bytes, etc.

I also cannot on-the-fly create a `#TempTable` due to max column size of 1,024.

The reasons the query is written a certain way are due to limitations of the system and network I am given, and cannot be adjusted nor can the query be run locally.

How do I get the sorted `DataTable` to work as that is what needs to be passed into the next function which is also outside of my control due to it being an api call to another system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really sort a `DataTable`. You do it via a `DataView`, as you have done, but that only sorts the view, not the table. If you then access the data via the `Rows` collection, you won't see the sort. You have to access the data via the `DataView`.

There's actually no need to create a `DataView` explicitly though. Every `DataTable` already has a `DataView` in its `DefaultView` property. When you bind a `DataTable` in WinForms, that's where the dusplayed data comes from. That's how you can sort the data in a `DataGridView` or via a `BindingSource`.

When you use the `Rows` collection, you get `DataRow` objects. When you use the `DefaultView`, you get `DataRowView` objects. They are quite similar in many ways but also have some differences. If you just want the data, you can index either using the column name and get the value, so they work the same way in that regard. If you access the data via the `DefaultView` but need the `DataRow` for some reason, you can access it via the `Row` property of the `DataRowView`. Try this code to see how it all works:

```cs
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("Peter");
table.Rows.Add("Paul");
table.Rows.Add("Mary");

Console.WriteLine("Rows, unsorted");

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["Name"]);
}

Console.WriteLine("DefaultView, unsorted");

foreach (DataRowView rowView in table.DefaultView)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rowView["Name"]);
}

table.DefaultView.Sort = "Name";

Console.WriteLine("Rows, sorted");

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["Name"]);
}

Console.WriteLine("DefaultView, sorted");

foreach (DataRowView rowView in table.DefaultView)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rowView["Name"]);
}

Console.WriteLine("DefaultView to DataRow, sorted");

foreach (DataRowView rowView in table.DefaultView)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rowView.Row.Field<string>("Name"));
}
```

You'll be able to see from that that the data in the `Rows` collection is the same before and after the sort whereas the `DefaultView` shows data in the specified order. The last loop shows how you can access the `DataRows` from the `DataRowViews` and then use them where `DataRowViews` can't be, e.g. in LINQ to DataSet methods.

Note that, if you really do require the `DataTable` itself to be sorted then you can call `ToTable` on the `DataView` to generate a new `DataTable`. The new table will contain data based on the `Sort` and `RowFilter` properties of the `DataView` and you can also omit some columns if you want. You can also specify that only distinct records should be included.

Comment: Since it's back in a "row" form, how do I pass that to the `DataTable` without explicited creating a for loop of every row (unless that's still fast enought)? i'm not looking for super speed but not a super slow process either

Comment: I also need all the 1,500 columns sorted which are in the DataView correctly but the last part of my question was that I need to pass it into a `DataTable` function from an API that I cannot adjust due to constraints in the business

Comment: @cdub, you can't really change the `DataTable` itself but you can generate a new `DataTable` from the `DataView`. See the last paragraph in my answer, which is a new addition.

Comment: Thx that should work